# Unable to open multiple workbook and append with data from an excel sheet using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet

I have an excel sheet with the list of excel workbooks in a column and corresponding data in the other column. I want to be able to open each workbook and fill a particular column with the correspending data only. Currently, my code opens each workbook and append with data of other workbook below it.

[image: Sample Excel Sheet]

My code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, N As Long, r As Range, x As Range

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\HP\Documents\test\script.xlsx"

For Each r In Range("A1:A3")
    With r

        Workbooks.Open r
        Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B3")
        For Each cell In Rng
        With cell

        Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y3:Y3")

    Rng.Copy r2
    End With
        Next cell
    End With

Next r

End Sub
```

Your input will be glady appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to copy and where?

Comment: You may want to specify which workbook a given sheet is in.

Comment: You have a `With` block but you are never actually using it. If you were to use a `With` block here, I would think it would be for the workbook you are opening maybe.

Comment: Also read up on code indentation!

Comment: @SJR take for instance, open the first file in column A and fill it with data in cell B2 and C2. Repeat the same for each of the file in column A, filling it with data in cells next to it

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are copying but I assuming you want to open each file in column A of your master file, extract some cells from that file and place it in the cells to the right of column A. This transfers a couple of cells so hopefully you can work out how to amend to your needs, or come back if not.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim r1 As Range, rng As Range, N As Long, r As Range, x As Range, wbMaster As Workbook, wb As Workbook

Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\Documents\test\script.xlsx")

For Each r In wbMaster.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A3")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(r)
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").value=r.Offset(, 1).Value  'this fills B1 of the workbook opened with B of the master file
    wb.close false
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried tweaking the code you shared but I'm still not able to get the ouput. Referring to the comment section of your code, this is what I hope to achieve  'this fills col B of the opened workbook with B1 of the master file. Thank you

Comment: Ah it's the other way round? So you have a list of filenames in file X, you open file Y and you want put B1 of X (master file) into B1 of file Y? Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You can also view it from this prespective, the username of each person that worked on each file listed in column A is what is in column B. So, I want to open each file and fill column say, Y of each file with the corresponding username.

Comment: Code amended above. You still haven't stated explicitly what goes where but hopefully you get the idea.